# Cant access custom widget instance when iterating through layout

Tags: python, pyqt6

I have a layout that I add a widget, class called ColList. When I run widget.children() I get an expected result, a list of widget. however when I try to run a method of ColList or access a variable pyqt crashes. For now I am trying to run a my sanity check method each ColList instance

I am using two .ui files. if you want me to post them I can. this is the (reduced) code I am trying to get to work

```py
class ColList(QWidget):
    def __init__(self, col, parent=None):
        super().__init__(parent)
        # Load the GUI
        uic.loadUi("Listwidget.ui", self)
        self.title = col
        self.groupBox.setTitle(col)
        print(self.parent())

    def SC(self):
        print("hi")


class MainWindow(QtWidgets.QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        uic.loadUi("MainWindow.ui", self)
        self.columns = ['a', 'b']
        self.loadTags
        

    def loadTags(self):
        for i in self.columns:
            # TagsH is the name of a Horizontal layout that is itself a child of a QScrollarea named scrollFilters
            self.TagsH.insertWidget(self.TagsH.count() - 1, ColList(f"{i}", parent=self))

    def applyFilters(self):
        # the print works it outputs: [<PyQt6.QtWidgets.QWidget object at 0x00000221161E2830>, <PyQt6.QtWidgets.QWidget object at 0x00000221161E28C0>]
        print(self.scrollFilters.children()[1:])
        
        # this print outputs an empty list
        print(self.TagsH.children())
        
        
        for i in self.scrollFilters.children()[1:]:
            # this part seems to crash the program
            i.widget().SC()
```

Comment: Don't cycle through children like this, and don't use `widget()` (the list already contains widgets, not layout items). Use `for child in self.scrollFilters.findChildren(ColList):` `child.SC()`

Comment: Thank you findChildren solved my problem. It's also much easier to use